# Basic nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am nesting resources like so:

```
resources :users do
  resources :tags
end
```

And in my tags index page, I want to link to the single tag page, so I am doing like:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', user_tag_path(@user.id) %>
```

In my controller I'm passing the curretly logged in user id:

```
@user = current_user
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"tags", :user_id=>1}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Tag` resource is dependent on a specific `User` resource. This means for a `Tag`'s `:show` route `user_tag`, it looks like this

```
user_tag GET  /users/:user_id/tags/:id(.:format)  tags#show
```

You need to specify both a `User` and a `Tag` on this route, like

```
user_tag_path(@user, @some_tag_here)
```

However, you say

> I want to link to the single tag page

which is poorly worded. I assume by this you mean you want to link to the `:index` route for `Tag`, specific to some `User` resourece. There is no "single tag page" defined like `/tags`.

The `:index` route looks like

```
  user_tags GET  /users/:user_id/tags(.:format)  tags#index
```

and is used like

```
user_tags_path(@user)
```

Comment: And in case you don't want to use current_user, I got it working by using: user_tag_path(tag.user.slug, tag.slug) (I'm using friendly ID)